# Changes made to component's string input does not change original string

Tags: angular, angular-components

When a component has a string input, and it makes change to that string input, changes don't change original data.
When doing the same thing with string array input it does change original data.

component-with-inputs.ts:

```
@Input('str') str:string;
@Input('strArray') str:string[];

changeFunc(){
    this.str = "changed"
    this.strArray.push("changed")
}
```

component-with-data.ts:

```
strData:string = "i am string";
strArrayData:string[] = ["i","am","array"]
```

component-with-data.html:

```
<component-with-inputs [str]="strData" strArray="strArrayData">
</component-with-inputs>
```

so when changeFunc is called original data on component-with-data will look like:

```
 "i am string";
["i","am","array","changed"]
```

string does't not change but string array does.
how can i make string also change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a 'string' is a value type while the array is a reference type.

```
<component-with-inputs [str]="strData" strArray="strArrayData">
</component-with-inputs>
```

In your above template, "strData" will be passed as value while "strArrayData" will be passed as a reference.

You should make your input property [value type] change emitted to the parent component. See following code -

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './your.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./your.component.css']
})
export class YourChildComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input('str') str: string;
  @Input() arr: Array<string>;
  @Output() strChange = new EventEmitter<string>();
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {


  }

  change() {
    this.strChange.emit('I am new string');
    this.arr.push('I am new string in array');
  }

}
```

In parent component template [notice the banana in the box notation] -

```
<app-child [(str)]="myString" [arr]="array"></app-child>
```

Comment: Thanks!!! What i happens if have more than one string input?  you need two emitters?

Comment: @Gigalala Yes, if you have two string input (or value type inputs), you need two emitters